How to write query for roles defined as Map object in angular and firestore?
I am using @angular/fire and I have a temples collection with below schema:
{
 name: 'Sri Chamundeshwari temple',
 address: 'Chamundi hills, Mysore',
 roles: {
  'owner@gmail.com': 'owner',
  'admin@gmail.com': 'admin',
  'member@gmail.com': 'member',
  'viewer@gmail.com': 'viewer'
 }
}

I want only the 4 users in the roles object to be able to access the temple document. Other users should be denied access.
I followed the guide in this link:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access
and structured my security rules as below:
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
    match /temples/{temple} {
    
      function isSignedIn() {
        return request.auth != null;
      }
    
      function getRole(rsc) {
        return rsc.data.roles[request.auth.token.email];
      }

      function isOneOfRoles(rsc, array) {
        return isSignedIn() && getRole(rsc) in array;
      }

      allow read: if isOneOfRoles(resource, ['owner', 'admin', 'member', 'viewer']);
    }
  }
}

How should I write a suitable query to get all temple documents which is accessible to logged in user?
The guide does not describe anything about queries.
I tried the below queries and they are giving permission errors.
ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Let's assume there are 10 temples in the collection.
User A has a role as viewer in 3 temples.
I am expecting that the below queries should return only 3 temples accessible to user A.
const q = query(
     collectionGroup(this.fireStore, "temples"), 
     where(`roles.${this.auth.currentUser?.email}`, 'array-contains', ['owner', 'administrator', 'member', 'viewer'])
);

const q = query(
        collection(this.fireStore, "temples"),
        where(`roles.${this.auth.currentUser?.email}`, 'array-contains', ['owner', 'administrator', 'member', 'viewer'])
);


Update: As per @Frank van Puffelen's answer, replaced the array-contains with in operator because in is the right one to use in this scenario and still receiving permission errors.

Please edit your question and add a screenshot of your database.

Screenshot added and I am logged in with the same email who is assigned role as owner.

You're using the array-contains operator on the roles.${this.auth.currentUser?.email}, but that field isn't an array.
To filter in whether a non-array field has one of a number of values, use the in operator.

As discussed in the comments, you'll need to use FieldPath as you have a . in your actual field name (which Firestore will otherwise interpret as a separator).

Roles array in security rules contains admin and in query contains administrator. Roles value in query can only be a sub-set of the roles array in security rules.

I just tried with the in operator and I am still getting permission error.

First off: does it make sense why the array-contains is the wrong operator to use here, and how the in operator would solve that? There may be more problems in what you shared, but this was definitely one of them - and the change in my answer fixes that part.

Yes, it definitely makes sense because array-contains should be used when the field value being queried itself is an array. In my case, field value is a string, and I need to check if the field value exists in the roles array. Hence, in operator is the right one to use here. I have updated the operator in question as well. Thank you.

Please don't make such breaking changes to an existing question, as right now my answer doesn't match with the new question anymore - which makes it much less useful to future visitors. :(

Right, I have reverted the breaking change. Instead, I have added one statement at the end of the question.

I think email cannot be used as a key for roles because they contain a period, and period determines a field path. So, something like, rules.owner@gmail.com in the query might be interpreted as field path - rules/owner@gmail/com. I tried with uid and it works correctly.

I am building a feature where one user can assign other users with various roles. Hence, I wanted to use email because emails can be communicated. UIDs cannot be communicated. So, how can a user with owner role assign another user some role if he does not know UID of another user?

For the .: in that case wrap the string (that includes the .) in a FieldPath object.

const fieldPath = new FieldPath('roles', this.auth.currentUser?.email as string); This works. Thank you.

If you can edit your answer to include the FieldPath point and the roles array mismatch point. I will mark your answer as accepted.
